# Raster images overlaying each other but shouldn't

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2

When I open a new map document and drag different raster images into the map the images stack on one another rather than form the complete image of a country. When I try zooming in, the multiple images flip back and forth in the same tile. The images are already georeferenced and have been used before without any problem. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: check the coordinate reference system for each raster.  It could be that they are all supposed to be different utm zones, but don't have a spatial reference defined.  That would cause them to stack up.  Also, what CRS does the data frame have?

Comment: What coordinates do you get when you wave the mouse over the screen? it sounds like you've lost your georeference... have you deleted or copied without world (tfw, jgw) files or header? What raster format are they? Do the details seem correct in ArcCatalog (right click on raster and go to properties).

Comment: They're all WGS84 UTM 20N and the dataframe has the same CRS. I haven't deleted any world files...but I'm also not seeing any of those file extensions. The rasterformat is .ecw and .ers. The details seems fine in ArcCatalog; here are pics of what I'm seeing http://imgur.com/sOv8XgR and http://imgur.com/opz7isc

Comment: Are you using the ers or ecw? both can be added to ArcMap... try removing the ers files and just use the ecw. Validate locations in ER_Viewer, QGIS or GDALINFO of just the ecw files and perhaps build a mosaic dataset in Esri or VRT using GDALBUILDVRT. BTW, ecw doesn't have world files as the georeference is internal but it can have ers info which *can* override the existing georeference - this is most likely to be your problem.